# custom string replace for time conversion

Tags: php, time, explode

Here is my input time, It may may have 0 or not

```
1. 01 or 1
```

or

```
2. 0601 or 601
```

or

```
3. 060101 or 60101
```

How can i do the time conversion with separation of `:` for each unit

So the output should be

```
1. 00:00:01
2. 00:06:01
3. 06:01:01
```

Comment: You just want to add a colon every 2 characters starting from the right?

Comment: Yes that's it considering the '0' as i given in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left pad your input to 6 characters using leading zeroes, split it into two character chunks, then implode with a `:` separator

```
echo implode(
    ':',
    str_split(
        str_pad($input, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
        2
    )
);
```

Comment: That was awesome answer !